# Viewport display issues in flat shading and material shading

Tags: 3d-view

I have an abc file imported and textured all good. The render in Cycles is all correct but it looks weird in both solid shading and material shading in the viewport. Eevee and workbench render also have the wrong look. I also find that zooming in will eliminate the "pieces" look in the mesh. Has anybody ever had this issue? How should I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the scale of your objects. If they are unusually small or big in relation to scene units (default is 1 meter). If the size is unusual, default viewport clipping values may not be adequate and what you observe is probably issues with viewport z-buffer precision, or "Z-fighting".

Adjust these values to fix it:

[image]

The smaller the difference between the near and far clipping planes, the more precision there is for the depth to be displayed correctly, so they should reflect reasonable distances in relation to your scene - the closest an object can be to the camera, and the furthest. If I have a building for interior visualisation and there are some wall panels or whatever as close to the walls as 0.005 meters(5mm) the default clipping values will give me the same issues, but if I adjusted near clipping plane to 0.02 and far to 300m that will still be more than enough to fit my scene, but the z-fighting issues will disappear.

Comment: I really appreciate it mate! Yes it is exactly what you described. I imported the abc file and the scale is quite wild, so I initially set the clip start to 0.000001, hence this z-depth fighting issue came up. Fixing it by setting it back to 0.01. I learned a lot! Thank you so much!